# Compactness of an infinite stairway with a isolated point.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Define $(X, \mathcal{T})$ to be the topological space given by $X=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{T}$ the product of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\pi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ denote the canonical projection.

Consider the sets:
$$N:=\bigcup_{k\geq 1} [0,1-1/k] \times \{k\}\quad\text{and}\quad M=N \cup \{(1,0)\}.$$

1. Prove that $M$ is compact but not closed and find its closure.
2. Given a closed subset $C\subset X$, prove that $C$ is compact if and only if $\pi(C)$ is bounded. Deduce that the closure of any compact set is compact.
3. Prove that $C\subset X$ is compact if and only if $\pi(C)$ is compact and $C \cap (\mathbb{R} \times \{k\}) $ is compact for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have no problems seeing that the closure of $M$ is $\overline{M}=[0,1] \times \mathbb{Z}$, but I cannot figure out why it is compact.
Also I see why $\pi(C)$  is bounded if $C$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem, but I do not see the other implication. Same with the third question - I see the left-to-right implication but not the reverse implication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints to start you off. Firstly, I think of $X$ like many "stalks", one for each copy of $\Bbb R$: you want to be thinking about achieving something for *most* of those stalks, and then sorting out the finitely many remaining stalks individually (it is dangerous to take that image too literally, since $\Bbb Z$ hasn't been given its discrete topology).

This mentality leads to a solution of question $(1)$ (which will help you address $(3)$ because the proofs are similar): mimic how we prove that the one-point compactification is genuinely compact, or how we prove that $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is genuinely a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ (without Heine-Borel). Given an open cover of $M$, take an open set that covers $(1,0)$: what remains of $M$ that is not covered? Not very much... only *finitely many* issues left to address. Oh, and question $(1)$ can be answered as a corollary of question $(3)$ if you're really stuck.

To be honest, figuring out why $N$ is not closed and $M=\overline{N}$ involves mostly the same trains of thought (for me) that you need to realise $M$ is compact.

For the other two questions:

> Exercise/Hint $(\rm i)$: Prove that $\pi$ is a closed map.

Reminder: *no*, that doesn't automatically follow just because it's a projection map. It also doesn't automatically follow "because $\Bbb Z$ is discrete" because that is not how $\Bbb Z$ is being topologised here. EDIT: of course the Tube lemma is also applicable here. I managed to forget that the first time…

Mostly it is the *proof* of this that will get you thinking about how to solve the rest of the problem, it is not an especially useful result in itself (in my solution). That said:

> Exercise/Hint $(\rm ii)$: Use $(\rm i)$ to show that in the situation of question $(2)$, $\pi(C)$ is actually compact, and that in the situation of question $(2)$ we have that  $C$ satisfies the hypotheses of question $(3)$. Thus if you can answer question $(3)$, you get a solution to the first part of $(2)$ as a corollary. For: "deduce the closure of any compact set is compact", do you remember "$f$ is continuous iff. $f(\overline{K})\subseteq\overline{f(K)}$ for all $K$"?

A hint for question $(3)$: assuming the hypotheses on $C$ and given an open cover of $C$ in $X$, you can extract a finite subset of the cover that will cover *most* of $C$, that is, for all but finitely many integers $k$ we have covered $\pi(C)\times\{k\}$ (bundling *most* of the stalks together). The finitely many remaining "issues" can be addressed analogously to how they are addressed in the solution of $(1)$ (a finite union of compact sets is...).

---

Solution to exercise $\rm(i)$:

> Take a closed $K\subseteq X$. Suppose $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\pi(K)$. For any $n\in\Bbb Z$, I know $(x,n)\notin K$ (otherwise $\pi(K)$ would contain $x$) and I know $K$ is closed therefore there will be an open neighbourhood of $(x,n)$ that avoids $K$. In particular there will be some open neighbourhoods $U_n$ of $x$ and $V_n$ of $n$ with $(U_n\times V_n)\cap K=\emptyset$. Idea: If $V_n=\Bbb Z$ happened, then $U_n$ would be a neighbourhood of $x$ and $U_n\cap\pi(K)=\emptyset$, and because $x$ is arbitrary we could conclude $\pi(K)$ is also closed. But, we might not be so lucky.

> Define $F:=\Bbb Z\setminus V_0$. This is **finite**. So, in the spirit of this post, it is *mostly* true that $U_0\cap\pi(K)=\emptyset$, so to speak. We just have finitely many problems, the elements of $F$. Define: $$U:=U_0\cap\bigcap_{n\in F}U_n$$Because $F$ is finite, $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$. Claim: $U\cap\pi(K)=\emptyset$. Given that claim is true, it follows - because $x$ is arbitrary - that $\pi(K)$ is closed.

> Suppose to the contradiction that there is some $y\in U\cap\pi(K)$. That means there is an integer $m$ with $(y,m)\in K$ and $y\in U$. Either $m\in F$, in which case because $y\in U_m$ and: $$(y,m)\in(U_m\times V_m)\cap K=\emptyset$$We have a contradiction, or $m\notin F$ i.e. $m\in V_0$, and because $y\in U_0$ we arrive at the same contradiction - by definition of $V_0$, $(y,m)\in(U_0\times V_0)\cap K=\emptyset$ which is absurd. The claim now follows, and because $K$ is arbitrary we get that $\pi$ is a closed map.

Comment: Sorry but I already realized that pi must be a closed map, but I don't see how to prove it, that's the problem.

Comment: @Superdivinidad Proving $\pi$ is a closed map should help you figure out the rest. Suppose $K\subseteq X$ is closed and $x\notin\pi(K)$. Then I know that $(x,n)\notin K$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. Because $K$ is closed, there shall exist basic product neighbourhoods $U_n\times V_n$ of each $(x,n)$ that do not intersect $K$. We can just take $U_0\times V_0$, say. It's not necessarily true that $U_0\cap\pi(K)=\emptyset$ but, the theme here is that this is *mostly* true in some sense. It *would* be true if $V_0=\Bbb Z$, but luckily we know $\Bbb Z\setminus V_0$ is finite, ... can you make a proof?

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: @Superdivinidad I've laid out a full solution to $\rm(i)$ in three stages, you can click on the boxes to reveal each stage

Comment: Thank you, I am very stuck with this problem.

Comment: @Superdivinidad For what it’s worth, that $\pi$ is a closed map follows from the Tube lemma, because $\Bbb Z$ with the cofinite topology is compact! I overlooked this the first time around. My proof $\pi$ is closed is doing essentially the same thing as proving the Tube lemma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146081/discussion-between-superdivinidad-and-fshrike).